# mysterious javascript error with django

Tags: javascript, django, debugging

I am including jquery in my template like so:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

After doing this,I add this form to my page:

```
<form method="POST">
Quantity: <input type="text" name="quantity" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Add To Cart"/>
</form>
```

My console then outputs the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'canPushDown'
```

The interesting thing is if I change the submit value to:

```
value="Add To Car"
```

The error disappears! Further more, If I add an extra t to the value:

```
value="Add To Cartt"
```

The error returns.

Here is my entire template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>

<form method="POST">
Quantity: <input type="text" name="quantity" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Add To Cart"/>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

I've confirmed this behavior is only occurring with the above html for django templates. Anyone have a hunch for what may be going on?

Comment: Your error is a js one, and there are no running scripts in your page [so far] - are you sure that wasn't a previous log?

Comment: mooonwave99: how would I clear the logs to tell for sure?

Comment: does your JavaScript Console gives you any errors?

Comment: Seerg: that is where I am seeing the error

Comment: Works fine in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7uEEP/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this to go away by disabling Amazon Universal Wishlist in Chrome Extensions

Comment: Can you please describe it more?

Answer (score 0):

I've come across the same thing, but not from errors captured in my own browser (I have a system setup to capture client side errors using raven-js and sentry).

My theory is that a Chrome browser extension is causing it. If you scan the extensions in your  Chrome profile for canPushDown you might find something.  If you do, I'd love to know what's causing it too.